# Controlling for covariates in a mediation model in process spss- How do i know the level of effect they have?

Tags: spss, mediation, predictor

I am checking for a mediation effect using the process plug in in SPSS.
I have 3 covariates included in addition to my IV,DV and Mediator.
In the output i receive from SPSS i can see the effect sizes while all three covariates are controlled. My question is- How do i know the effect of each covariate. How do i know the extent to which they effect?
Thanks!

Comment: You typically control for covariates to get valid estimates of your direct and indirect effects: usually in mediation analysis the problem is identifying and include in the model possible confounders, not estimation and inference about them.